# Not able to boot after building kernel for BBG (using microSD)

Tags: linux-kernel, cross-compiling, boot, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

My aim is to cross compile a new Linux Kernel for a BeagleBone Green. I've successfully completed all the steps
that were needed to build the kernel and deploy it.

Using the following tutorial
https://embedjournal.com/kernel-compilation-beaglebone-black/

I have a microSD card with rootfs and BOOT partition.
rootfs has the kernel modules and BOOT has MLO, u-boot.img, uImage
and uEnv.txt.

After putting the SD card into the BBG and pressing the S2 button, LEDs don't blink.
But when I press the Power button, LEDs start blinking but BBG doesn't boot with that.

**So my question here is that do I need to have an OS already flashed to the BBG internal eMMC and then
insert a SD card which has the built kernel?**

Or is it fine to have nothing into the BBG and then by just inserting the prepared SD card I can boot into it.

**My second question - Is it necessary to have a USB to serial cable here?**
I am not using a USB to serial cable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## It's important to understand how the "S2" button changes the behaviour of Beaglebone type AM335x boards:

When power is applied, the AM335x SoC "looks" at a few of its connection pins, one of them is going through the button labeled "S2". It *only* does this **once** and behaviour remains fixed until power is removed.

- If "S2" is pressed when powering on, then it will first look at the micro-SD slot. More accurately it will try the following things: SPI, **micro-SD**, USB, UART.
- If "S2" is *not* pressed when powering on, then it will first look at the eMMC. More accurately it will try the following things: **eMMC**, micro-SD, UART, USB

[Please note that "USB" is a special device mode and does not imply capability to boot directly from USB mass storage!]

### But what does it mean "it looks at X"?

It means that the internal minimal boot code looks for a source of bootloader. This is often referred to as MLO or SPL or X-Loader. It's a first stage that then loads the main bootloader, in this case U-Boot.

There are many ways to provide the SPL. The [AM335x Technical Reference Manual (revision P)](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruh73p/spruh73p.pdf) Chapter 26.1.2 "Architecture", Figure 26-1 shows this as the underlying HW (hardware) layer. I will only cover MMC and SD, for further details, please read the TRM.

### But why does it boot from SD if I don't press the button on power up?
*or:* U-Boot also makes choices.

It's complicated. There are *many ways™*.

1. Foremost it will first check the eMMC, if it finds a SPL at some magic locations, it will execute it and then that will execute U-Boot
2. If it didn't find anything on the eMMC, then it checks for an inserted SD card and proceeds as above. If it doesn't find a SPL on a SD, it will try USB mode and UART0 too.
3. Once U-Boot takes over it follows its own logic, possibly modified by a `uEnv.txt`. This sounds innocent, but what it means is that even if U-Boot was loaded from eMMC (priority!) it can still decide that there is an SD card inserted and it will load the Linux kernel from there! *most likely what happened to @shreeya-patel*

### Answer 1: eMMC can be blank

To avoid such easily confusing situations it often helps to wipe the eMMC to reduce the number of variables that can mess with things. The easiest way to do this is boot a recent beagleboard.org image from SD card and execute `sudo blkdiscard /dev/mmcblk1`. This will **erase everything from eMMC**. The result is that for the average user the behaviour is reduced to: **It will always try to read everything from SD-card**. If something is wrong with SPL, U-Boot or the kernel, then booting will fail reproducibly.

I've allowed myself for some simplifications and minor omissions. Feel free to ask, but also consider reading up about those topics.

## Do I need a USB-to-serial adapter?

Not if you get everything 100% right and the system boots perfectly fine to at least a point where you can interact with it either over USB, Ethernet or WiFi.

**If booting fails at any step due to the most minute detail, you will most likely have no way to find out what happened!** And this was the reason for this question.

Personally, I mark days where I created something from scratch and *it worked the first time* red in my calendar. I think I might have 2 such marked days by now, in many years and even then there were other failures on those days.

That is why I consider a USB-to-serial adapter an essential tool.

Also the price for the cheapest types of adapters on eBay or on one of the shopping platforms like Aliexpress or Banggood has dropped below 1€/1US$. I always have a couple of spares and for devices that I work with more often I will leave the debug UART adapter attached permanently for sheer convenience.

The amount of simple, yet incredibly valuable introspection makes it essential. It will alow you you to understand things much better, progress faster and design more reliable systems.

Comment: @shreeya-patel - does this help you in understanding what happens during boot?

Comment: Yes, totally! All my concepts have been cleared. Thanks for the perfect answer.

Comment: Hey I've got one more problem. I noticed that I am not able to use i2cdetect or not even being able to echo adt7516 0x48 > new_device ( gives me error saying that new_device permission denied ). I noticed that I2C support has not been enabled into the config file. When I do "sudo make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- bb.org_defconfig" on my host machine , this doesn't enable I2C support. What should I do here? Any suggestions?

Comment: I just solve it by manually configuring it with sudo make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- menuconfig

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell from your description. You'll have to hold down 'S2' while you connect power to the BBB for the ROM-loader to look at the SD-card for MLO/SPL.

**Yes, a USB-serial (UART, "FTDI") cable with 3.3V levels (in case of the BBB) is essential for low level embedded work.** Especially when working with bootloaders or kernels. In this case it will allow you to see at which stage you have a problem: MLO, U-Boot or Kernel and then work on it further.

Comment: I asked Robert Nelson about the USB to serial cable and he told me that it is not necessary to have it. Also, S2 button didn't work. I was able to boot by holding power button during the connection. I'll soon post the solution for my question. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: You don't have to own one, no. It does make troubleshooting anything in the boot process that happens before your device answers over USB or Ethernet incredibly hard. That's why I described it as essential and I stand by my opinion. I doubt that Robert would see it differently when asked "Do you need a USB serial cable for troubleshooting bootloader and kernel boot problems".

Answer (score 0):

You need an FTDI cable attached to header J1 on the BBG in order to do serial debugging  to see what is happening during boot, see what is happening when the kernel is starting, and to take control of u-boot. Just to clarify, hold down S2 while plugging in the power to the device to boot from a (bootable) SD card. Unless you wiped it, the eMMC(on board storage) of the BBG already contains the u-boot.img and MLO. When you boot and hold down S2, uboot (on the eMMC) knows to boot from the sdCard. If you want to change u-boot.img or the MLO file, you have to use the dd command to write it to the eMMC of the BBG.

I have a x-compiled kernel boot remotely on my BBG using TFTP and the rootfs mounted over NFS.

"do I need to have an OS already flashed to the BBG internal eMMC and then insert a SD card which has the built kernel?"
ans: No. It is possible to boot the BBG with nothing on it but the BIOS and the secondary bootloader (everything else is remote). If you are completely unable to boot the BBG, You should put the latest OS image from the BB website onto the SD card and boot from that to start fresh.

Let me know if you have any questions.

edit: I use `minicom` for serial debugging

Edit 2: I would highly discourage you from wiping the whole MMC unless absolutely necessary

Answer (score -1):

So the answer to the first question is that it is not necessary to have a BeagleBone with a flashed image in it. 
Just by putting the prepared SD card into the SD card slot, one can boot through it.

For booting through your prepared SD card...

1. Hold down the power button during connection.
2. With 'dmesg | grep tty' check which ttyX (console port) is shown up.
3. Within your terminal, type 'sudo screen /dev/ttyX 115200' (here X will be your console port number).

You should now be able to login to your arm device.

Answer to the second question is that it is not necessary to have a USB to serial cable here.
It is optional.

Comment: Your "solution" shows a significant misunderstanding of the workings. It may have worked for you *in your particular situation*, but is by no means a generic solution that answers the question posed. Also it makes silent assumptions about the Linux distribution. I understand that you're a beginner, but please try to keep in mind that stack overflow questions/answers are meant to benefit *everyone* in a similar situation.

Comment: To unfold this: **1** - it is irrelevant if you hold down the power button; **2** - That only applies if your "user space" aka Linux distribution exposes a TTY over USB (like `/dev/ttyUSB0` or `/dev/ttyACM0`); **3** - it's not "ttyX" it's tty**USB**X or tty**ACM**X; You'll only be able to log in if there is a getty listening with a login, which it does on the beagleboard.org images, but not necessarily on others.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. Can you please let me know that where am I wrong?

Comment: Please avoid my previous comment. Thanks for your solution. Yes I am a beginner so after getting the solution, I just got excited and posted the solution to help others. If you don't mind can you please put an answer for this question, maybe a more detailed one so that it will be useful for others and I'll accept that answer. Thanks

Comment: It's not about the "Internet points" for me ;-) It's really about both questions and answers being meaningful contributions. I'll write an answer to the question, as I now understand still a bit better what you were after. I might also try to make your question easier to understand by editing it. I've been in your place too once, so don't be discouraged and keep learning new things.

Comment: Yes, it's not about the "Internet points" for me too otherwise I would have edited my answer and put it in a better way as you told me. But as you have given the correct answer so the credit goes to you ;)